# XCode 4 Debugger: Attach to process from command line

Tags: xcode, shell, debugging, process, applescript

I would like to launch an application from the command line and immediately attach the graphical debugger in XCode 4 to it, without having to click in the Xcode menu Product->Attach To Progress. Is it possible to script this using a bash or Apple script?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work in the Xcode-Beta Version 6.2 (6C121). For Xcode, just change "Xcode-Beta" to Xcode. Also, you'll want to change the process name "Staging" to the process you'd like to attach.

```
tell application "Xcode-Beta"
activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Xcode"
        click (menu item "By Process Identifier (PID) or Name…" of menu 1 of menu item "Attach to Process" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Debug" of menu bar 1)
    end tell
    tell application process "Xcode"
        set value of text field 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 to "Staging"
    end tell
    tell application process "Xcode"
        click button "Attach" of sheet 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked for Xcode 12

```
tell application "Xcode"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Xcode"
        click (menu item "Attach to Process by PID or Name…" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Debug" of menu bar 1)
        
    end tell
    tell application process "Xcode"
        set value of text field 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 to "Your App/Process Name"
    end tell
    tell application process "Xcode"
        click button "Attach" of sheet 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell

tell application "our App/Process Name"
    activate
end tell
```